# Python Alternative to npm set strict ssl false

Tags: python, macos, npm, terminal, pip

I am using a school computer (macbook) to code and the administrator has installed software which returns an ssl error whenever I use pip or npm. I know with npm I can use `npm set strict-ssl false` and was wondering if there was a similar way to do this with pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5448

Passing `--trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org` as options should make it trust these domains.

Comment: How do I put these into the terminal?

Comment: `pip install <package> --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org`